# Removing rows in R where the contiguous values of rows in one column are further than 1 numeric value apart, whilst accounting for participant ID?

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, data-cleaning

I am trying to clean up a timeseries with multiple data points. The data is arranged by day and by 'beep'. I want to only keep items that are 1 beep away from each other on the same day.

In order to do this I have created a dummy variable by multiplying day number by 10 and adding the beep number to it.

I was wondering if it would be possible to use some kind of clause to specify that I want to keep data that is contiguously = 1 to its lead OR lag variable, but also less than 50 (so that it will keep the days isolated). Alternatively is there a way to group by participant and then by day so that it will apply across participant and across each day in a way that won't delete incorrect data between days e.g. it should not delete day 2 beep 1 for being too far away from day 1 beep 7.

I am doing this so I can use a function called lagvar from an ESM package to created a time-lagged series. Before doing this I want to make sure that any variables in day_beep that are greater than 1 from their contiguous neighbours are removed.

E.g.
Take the following rows and day_beep values

```
Participant ID              Day        Beep        Dummy Variable 
    1                          1         1             101
    1                          1         2             102
    1                          1         4             104   
  **1                          1         7             107**
    1                          2         3             203
    1                          2         4             204
    2                          1         2             102
    2                          1         3             103
  **2                          2         5             205
    2                          3         4             305**
  **3                          1         1             101**
    3                          2         4             204
    3                          2         5             205
  **4                          1         7             107**
    4                          4         4             404
    4                          4         5             405
```

In this instance I would want to remove the data held between the asterisks as it is either contiguously more than 1 beep from its neighbours, or an isolated beep in the series.

What would be the easiest way to do this for the entire dataframe?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: For Day 1, Beep  2 - 4 difference is 2..  Are you looking for more than 2

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lead` and `lag` from `dplyr` to keep only the rows that have a contiguous value before or after:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(Participant_ID) %>% 
  filter(((Dummy_Variable - lag(Dummy_Variable)) == 1) |
           (lead(Dummy_Variable) - Dummy_Variable == 1))
```

output

```r
   Participant_ID   Day  Beep Dummy_Variable
 1              1     1     1            101
 2              1     1     2            102
 3              1     2     3            203
 4              1     2     4            204
 5              2     1     2            102
 6              2     1     3            103
 7              3     2     4            204
 8              3     2     5            205
 9              4     4     4            404
10              4     4     5            405
```

Comment: This seems to have worked...thank you so much! Will need to apply it to the full data-set tonight but fingers crossed.